# Ember.js with multiple Master-Detail Views

Tags: ember.js

As much as I've read, `Ember.js` currently does not support the notion of having multiple instances of a single controller without enabling the experimental `{{control}}` helper.

As I understand it, the Ember-y way to do a sorted list is to define a property on the Controller that performs the sort, a la:

```
App.BarController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  beers: (function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.createWithMixins(Ember.SortableMixin, {
      sortProperties: ['rating'],
      content: this.get('content.beers')
    })
  }).property('content.beers')
});
```

In my application, I'd like to display all of the beers on tap at a bar, and sort those beers by rating.  This is done fairly straightforward for **one** bar using the normal master-detail pattern, given a `App.BarController`.  However, if I want to show two bars side-by-side, suddenly this model breaks.  I can't use `{{render}}` within an `{{each}}` (since `render` can only be called once), and the following scenario breaks as well, as the data-bindings are updated to only show the *last* bar.

```
{{#each bar in controller}}
  {{#with bar as controller}}
    {{view BarView}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Finally, I can't just use `{{view}}` as that removes the ability to sort the data by rating.  The view must be bound to a controller, or some other mechanism for sorting.

**TL;DR:** Given a `App.Bar` that `hasMany` instances of `App.Beer`, using `Ember.SortableMixin` makes it straightforward to create a sorted list.  However, if I want to display *two* `App.Bar`s at the same time (for comparison), this method breaks as it would require two instances of `App.BarController`, which is not possible.  What is the correct way to get two sorted lists based on the content of two objects of the same class?

Answer (score 2):

> What is the correct way to get two sorted lists based on the content of two objects of the same class?

Generally you want to stick to one-controller-per-list. So in this case I would suggest having, say `App.LeftBarController` and `App.RightBarController`.

Of course there will be shared code but that can be refactored into a base class or mixin.

Comment: And when there are N-Many instances?

Comment: I'm also curious how this would extend to an uncertain number of instances.

Comment: I don't think the approach I described scales well to n-Many instances. In that scenario you would be looping over the `n-Many` objects, probably via `{{each}}` helper with `itemController="App.BarController"`.